# Solve under given group

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've created the group (its GF4 algebra) that has 4 elements:

```
OrderMat = {0, 1, lambda, lambda + 1}
```

And definition of operation (.) with this Matrix realized by function:

```
         |   0   |   1    |   lambda   |   lambda+1   |
        ______________________________________________
       0||   0   |   0    |      0     |       0      |
       1||   0   |   1    |   lambda   |   lambda+1   |
  lambda||   0   | lambda |  lambda+1  |       1      |
lambda+1||   0   |lambda+1|     1      |     lambda   |


OPMatrix =         {{0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, lambda, lambda + 1},
        {0, lambda, lambda + 1, 1},
        {0, lambda + 1, 1, lambda}}

GF4Mult[x_, y_] := OPMatrix[[Position[OrderMat, x][[1]][[1]]]][[Position[OrderMat, y][[1]][[1]]]]
```

Now I would like to Solve equations in this group.
for example:

```
Solve[x.lambda == 1,x]      ... x=>lambda+1
```

or like this:

```
Solve[GF4Mult[x,lambda]== 1,x]      ... x=>lambda+1
```

Is this possible ? do i have to use some other structure to define group ?

Comment: Although this is on-topic here on [so], it's also on-topic on [mathematica.se].

Comment: (by the way, don't chain `Part`. Use `[[1, 1, Position ...]]`.

Comment: You might see if you can get a look at the book "Exploring Abstract Algebra With Mathematica." You can see some of the contents of that if you look it up on Amazon. I believe that likely shows how to do exactly the kind of things you are interested in. With each new version of the book the support files were modified slightly and updates are available on the author's site, but I think the author got tired of doing that and hasn't done version 11, but the needed changes should be none or minimal and it might be a learning experience if you do need to figure out how to do that. Buy cheap used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good way of doing this, but it seems closer to what you are asking for than the last couple of things I tried. And it uses the notation that you chose, except for Mathematica reordering lambda+1 to be 1+lambda on output.

First let's define your multiplication operator

```
times={{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,lambda,0},{0,lambda+1,0},
  {1,0,0},{1,1,1},{1,lambda,lambda},{1,lambda+1,lambda+1},
  {lambda,0,0},{lambda,1,lambda},{lambda,lambda,lambda+1},{lambda,lambda+1,1},
  {lambda+1,0,0},{lambda+1,1,lambda+1},{lambda+1,lambda,1},{lambda+1,lambda+1,lambda}};
```

That is exactly what you had except for my flattening that into a vector.

Now lets show a method somewhat similar to `Solve` that might work for you.

Suppose as a first example you wonder is there a lambda+1*something=lambda+1

```
Cases[times,{lambda+1,x_,lambda+1}]
```

and that shows you there is only one value which satisfies that, the identity.

```
{{1+lambda,1,1+lambda}}
```

Another example

```
Cases[times,{lambda+1,x_,lambda}]
```

gives you

```
{{1+lambda,1+lambda,lambda}}
```

Another example, is there lambda+1*anythingBUTlambda+1=lambda

```
Cases[times,{lambda+1,Except[lambda+1],lambda}]
```

gives you

```
{}
```

which shows there is no such value.

Another example

```
Cases[times,{lambda+1,x_,Except[x_]}]
```

gives you

```
{{1+lambda,1,1+lambda},{1+lambda,lambda,1},{1+lambda,1+lambda,lambda}}
```

That has a lot of flexibility because you can have unknowns in any position. But because of that flexibility it doesn't just return a single value to you. Perhaps you can use this for what you are thinking of or perhaps you can think of ways to adapt this to what you are trying to do.

If you want to extract one value of a result then you can do things like this:

```
 Cases[times,{lambda+1,x_,lambda}:>x]
```

which will return

```
{1+lambda}
```

which is the value, or values, of x which satisfied that.

Check this carefully to see if you can find any mistakes before you depend on it.

Comment: Thanks. I can use that. I wanted to Solve a system of linear equations. So with this i can do that. And this leads me to another question. Is there a way to solve under algebra, such as under GF4 (+, . )??  of course i have table for (+) operation as well.

Comment: And at the end i find out for this example i can go around this. because as mentioned i have group of 4 part of GF4 algebra. and since its algebra it can be created by irecudible polynom. And then i can use classic Solve and then just modulo result by the polynom.  But that cant be done for groups of size forexample 6 (it can be done for groups of size equal to power of some prime number).